# Can't get preg_replace_callback function working

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

It won't work, if you see anything wrong..

```
function replaceLink($matches){
    $final = '<img src=\''.$path[$matches[1]].'\' alt=\''.$data['alt'].'\'/>';
    return $final;
}
$message = preg_replace_callback('#\[img\]([1-3])\[/img\]#isU', 'replaceLink', $message);
```

How may I use variables which were declared outside of the function?

Comment: Wont work? Or doesn't work correctly? What is the value of `$message`?

Comment: You'll be more likely to get help if you can provide a link to a jsfiddle or something similar that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the function, you're passing a string:

```
$message = preg_replace_callback('...', 'replaceLink', $message);
```

It should be this:

```
$message = preg_replace_callback('...', replaceLink, $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling function in this way

```
$message = preg_replace_callback('#\[img\]([1-3])\[/img\]#isU', 'replaceLink', $message);
```

is ok. And should work.

But I see that in your function `replaceLink()`

```
function replaceLink($matches){
    $final = '<img src=\''.$path[$matches[1]].'\' alt=\''.$data['alt'].'\'/>';
    return $final;
}
```

you use variables which are not defined in that frunction `$path`, `$data`. 
If they are defined outside the function and they are not global then they will be null inside `replaceLink()` and you should get error.

Try to use this code

```
$message = preg_replace_callback( 
    '#\[img\]([1-3])\[/img\]#isU', 
    function($matches) use ($path, $data) {
         $final = '<img src=\''.$path[$matches[1]].'\' alt=\''.$data['alt'].'\'/>';
         return $final;
    }, 
    $message 
);
```

Comment: I use external variables, that's true, how may I use them?

Comment: Could you provide the code where you define `$path` and `$data`?

Comment: I finally figured out that i had to put Global $path, $data inside of my function!